# How to iterate over Query List of django model

Tags: python, json, django

I am reading a json file from a website and if the record is not in my Customers queryset I want to create a new Customer for that record. What is happening is when I iterate over the queryset, Django is trying to create a new Customer even when it is already in the queryset.

Please see my code below:

```
from rest_framework import generics
from customer.models import Customers
from .serializers import CustomersSerializer
import json
import urllib.request

class CustomerAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    j = urllib.request.urlopen("https://web.njit.edu/~jsd38/json/customer.json")
    customer_data = json.load(j)
    queryset1 = Customers.objects.values_list('CustomerId', flat=True)
    for customer in customer_data:
        if customer["@Id"] not in queryset1.iterator():
            CustomerId = customer["@Id"]
            Name = customer["Name"]
            PhoneNumber = customer["PhoneNumber"]
            EmailAddress = customer["EmailAddress"]
            StreetLine = customer["Address"]["StreetLine1"]
            City = customer["Address"]["City"]
            StateCode = customer["Address"]["StateCode"]
            PostalCode = customer["Address"]["PostalCode"]
            cus = Customers()
            cus.CustomerId = CustomerId
            cus.Name = Name
            cus.PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber
            cus.EmailAddress = EmailAddress
            cus.StreetLine = StreetLine
            cus.City = City
            cus.StateCode = StateCode
            cus.PostalCode = PostalCode
            cus.save()
    queryset = Customers.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomersSerializer
```

Comment: It should work, although you don't need `.iterator()` (`if customer["@Id"] not in queryset1` would work also). There must be another reason why the json value is not in the values list: str versus int?

Comment: have you printed the queryset and the JSON data to see if it is really present? And are you sure that both have the same data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is returning strings for the "@Id" key, I'm assuming your model `Customers` has integers as `CustomerId` field.

You should convert them to `str` or `int`:

```
if int(customer["@Id"]) not in queryset1:
    ...
```